# Android WebRTC supported codec

Tags: android, webrtc, h.264

I just read in a thread on google that is not possible for Honor and Huawei to encode to H264 when using webrtc :
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/discuss-webrtc/huawei$20h264%7Csort:date/discuss-webrtc/EA14U8FMT_k/Jn3CEG7YCQAJ

Is that true ???
That seem really strange, that we couldn't do that...

also, I read that thread because, I arrive to encode my stream with a Samsung but not with a Huawei P20. (with Huawei the stream created stay PV8 instead with other device I tested who are H.264)

Here it's the code in WebRTC that prove to the guy that is not supported buy Huawei and Honor :

```
final ArrayList<MediaCodecProperties> supported_codecs = new ArrayList<MediaCodecProperties>();
    supported_codecs.add(qcomH264HwProperties);
    supported_codecs.add(exynosH264HwProperties);
    if (PeerConnectionFactory.fieldTrialsFindFullName("WebRTC-MediaTekH264").equals("Enabled")) {
      supported_codecs.add(mediatekH264HwProperties);
    }
    return supported_codecs.toArray(new MediaCodecProperties[supported_codecs.size()]);
 }
```

I can add piece of my code if needed.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: I just see that , so I think it's true https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/discuss-webrtc/huawei/discuss-webrtc/VN_YQDbI_ec/xAcgvOxTCgAJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its bad, if you look in the source code [here](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/master/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/HardwareVideoEncoderFactory.java#235) (function isHardwareSupportedInCurrentSdkH264()) there are no mention of hisilicon just qualcomm exynos.

I've seen people solve this problem in this [issue](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues/467) just forcing the sdp in the offer but it doesnt work for me.

Comment: Okey, thanks to reply me. Do you know if I we add in the webrtc code (in the  function isHardwareSupportedInCurrentSdkH264) hisilicon restriction, if it's work ?

Comment: also I will try to forcing the sdp

Comment: Do you know if they will fix this bug soonly like they are on it or they don't matter

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it will be fixed, i think not...
You can switch to vp8 codec, it has sw encode/decode fallback and it works on huawei devices.